# how to use data type as "raster" during migration in Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent

I am trying to include `raster` datatype in a migration file, but it is giving me the following error:

> Method Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::raster does not exist.

##### Migration

```php
Schema::create('bi.defaultplant_date', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('rid');
    $table->raster('rast');
    $table->text('filename');
});
```

Comment: What is `raster` data type? I have never heard it. Should that be added by a composer package you are requiring? `raster` does not exist on Laravel by default, you need to add more info about it

Comment: i am using Postgres database where i need to store raster data with rater datatype. I know raster doesn't exist in laravel but is there any alternative datatype that works as raster data type?